# onClick in button element not triggering re-render in react-table when using react hooks with graphql

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, react-table

I'm trying to render a table using react-table, however, this table has different states that are being pulled from a GraphQL database. Each button should effectively render the same UI for the table, but only display the shipments that have the correct status associated with what button the user clicked.

My shipments query is as follows:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

export const GET_SHIPMENTS = gql`
      {
        shipments {
          created_at
          id
          status
          orders {
            order_items
          }
        }
      }
    `;
```

My table component using the `GET_SHIPMENTS` query looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { GET_SHIPMENTS } from '../graphql/ShipmentQueries';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';

import {
  Card,
  CardBody,
  Row,
  ButtonGroup,
  Button
} from "reactstrap";

function OrderTable ({ loading, shipments }) {
  const [shownShipment, setShownShipment] = useState({status: "created"});

  const columns = [
    {
      Header: 'ID',
      accessor: 'id',
    },
    {
      Header: 'Status',
      accessor: 'status',
    },
    {
      Header: 'Item Count',
      accessor: 'orders[0].order_items'
    },
    {
      Header: 'Time Stamp',
      accessor: 'created_at',
    },
  ];

if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    return (
        <div className="content">
            <ButtonGroup className="center">
                <Button 
                  name="created" 
                  onClick={() => setShownShipment(shownShipment.status === "created")}
                >
                  Created
                </Button>

                <Button 
                  name="awaiting driver" 
                  onClick={() => setShownShipment(shownShipment.status === "awaiting_driver")}
                >
                  Awaiting Driver
                </Button>

                <Button 
                  name="delivered" 
                  onClick={() => setShownShipment(shownShipment.status === "delivered")}
                >
                  Delivered
                </Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
          <Row className="mt-5">
              <Card>
                <CardBody>
                  <ReactTable
                    data={shipments}
                    columns={columns}
                    sortable={true}
                    resizable={false}
                    minRows={10}
                  />
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
          </Row>
        </div>
    );
  }

  export const OrderTableWithData = graphql(GET_SHIPMENTS, {
    props: ({data: { loading, shipments, shownShipments }}) => ({
      loading,
      shipments,
      shownShipments,
    }),
  })(OrderTable);
```

This is my first introduction into using hooks, so I know that I'm probably not utilizing them properly. I'm not sure if I have to use the `useEffect` hook or not. I've scoured the Hooks docs and can't seem to find a clear answer. I feel like `useState` should work. Do I have to re-render the entire ReactTable element?

Comment: When you call setShownShipment on button press in this way, you're setting shownShipment to true or false depending on the current status. So, its starting out as "created" and then it's becoming either true or false. Is this what you are intending? I think you may be trying to do something like 'setShownShipment({status: 'delivered' )' in the delivered button press case.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to say the status is true or false. I want to change the status,  thus updating the state of the table in order to show that, if they click the `Delivered` button, the state should update to `delivered` and then render the table displaying only the shipments that are delivered. Maybe in my hook, I should leave an empty string? Because if I put the intial state as `created` then inside of my button, I guess I would have to do a tertiary?

Comment: The buttonClick code you are currently running is only setting shownStatus to true or false, because (shownShipment.status === "created") only resolves to true or false. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want shownShipment.status to be the string corresponding to the delivery status (such as 'delivered', 'awaiting_driver') etc, your buttonClick code should look like this:

```
onClick={() => setShownShipment({status: "delivered"}) }
```

Try adding an effect to the react component like this to see the status updating after you click each button:

```
useEffect(() => { console.log(shownShipment); }, [shownShipment]);
```

Now that you have shownShipment set to the desired status, you can filter your total list of shipments from GQL based on this. UseState again for the list of shipments you will actually give to your table. useEffect will be helpful here as well. Something like this:

```
// at the top of the component
var [shipmentsToDisplay, setShipmentsToDisplay] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    // loop through all shipments and create a new array for only the ones 
    // you want to show.
    const filteredShipments = 
        shipments && 
            shipments.map(shipment => {
                if (shipment.status === shownShipment) {
                    return shipment;
                }
            }

    setShipmentsToDisplay(filteredShipments);
}, [shownShipment, shipments]);


// Render your table with these shipments rather than props.shipments
<ReactTable
    data={shipmentsToDisplay}
    columns={columns}
    sortable={true}
    resizable={false}
    minRows={10}       
/>
```

Comment: So I think that may be the first step in this, however, when I actually click the buttons, the table doesn't filter to _only_ show those shipments that are _delivered_ or what have you. I guess I should have been more specific as to what I wanted the buttons to do. I originally had a `filterShipments` function but didn't know how to pass it down to the onClick handler.

Comment: In the console, I am getting the object that is associated with the status, so it looks like that is correct.

Comment: Check my edit, I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I think this is good for filtering, but for some reason, I'm getting this error under `setShipmentsToDisplay(filteredShipments)`

```var setShipmentsToDisplay: (value: React.SetStateAction<any[]>) => void
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  24 |             }
  25 | 
> 26 |     setShipmentsToDisplay(filteredShipments);
     |     ^
  27 | }, [shownShipment, shipments]);
  28 | 
  29 |eslint
',' expected.ts(1005)```

Comment: So this still isn't working for some reason, not sure where to go from here. I had to comment out so it would display data so I could work on some other things.

Comment: It looks like that might be a syntax error.. I didn't check to make sure my code compiles, so please add a console statement for filteredShipments after the map function to make sure that it looks as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this code was as follows:
(Some code removed for brevity)

```
function OrderTable ({ loading, shipments }) {
  const [shipmentsToDisplay, setShipmentsToDisplay] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(shipments) {
      filterShipments("created");
    }
  }, [shipments]);

  function filterShipments(status) {
    let shownShipments = [];
    shipments.forEach(element => {
      if(element.status === status) {
        shownShipments.push(element);
      }
    });
    setShipmentsToDisplay(shownShipments);
  }

if (loading) return <Loading />;
    return (
        <div className="content">
            <ButtonGroup className="center">
                <Button name="pending" onClick={() => filterShipments("created")}>
                  Pending
                </Button>
                <Button name="ready" onClick={() => filterShipments("awaiting_driver")}>
                  Ready
                </Button>
                <Button name="completed" onClick={() => filterShipments("delivered")}>
                  Completed
                </Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
          <Row className="mt-5">
            <ReactTable
              data={shipmentsToDisplay}
              columns={columns}
              sortable={true}
              resizable={false}
              defaultPageSize={5}
              className="-striped -highlight"
              getTrProps={getTrProps}
              SubComponent={row => {
                return (
                  <ShipmentDetails
                    shipments={shipments}
                  />
                )
              }}
            />
          </Row>
        </div>
    );
  }

  export const OrderTableWithData = graphql(GET_SHIPMENTS, {
    props: ({data: { loading, shipments }}) => ({
      loading,
      shipments
    }),
  })(OrderTable);
```

The solution was to land on the `Pending` shipments, so for my state, I used the `useEffect` hook to land on the shipments that have `created` as a status.

For my onClick function, I decided to filter through each shipment starting with the `created` shipments and update the state based on which status is associated with the button click. I don't know if that makes sense or not. I'm new to hooks and GraphQL.